# MySQL truncated some rows of int data type year column

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

importing csv file to mysql workbench table, but MySQL automatically truncates some rows of the year column though the year column is a normal INT datatype, does anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS olympic_history;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS olympic_history(
id      int,
name    varchar(100),
sex varchar(20),
age varchar(20),
height  varchar(10),
weight  varchar(10),
team    varchar(50),
noc varchar(20),
games   varchar(40),
year    int,
season  varchar(40),
city    varchar(40),
sport   varchar(40),
event   varchar(100),
medal   varchar(20)
);
```

**Error**

> - Row import failed with error: ("Data truncated for column 'year' at row 1",1265)

```
"ID","Name","Sex","Age","Height","Weight","Team","NOC","Games","Year","Season","City","Sport","Event","Medal" 
"1","A Dijiang","M",24,180,80,"China","CHN","1992 Summer",1992,"Summer","Barcelona","Basketball","Basketball Men's Basketball",NA
"2","A Lamusi","M",23,170,60,"China","CHN","2012 Summer",2012,"Summer","London","Judo","Judo Men's Extra-Lightweight",NA
"3","Gunnar Nielsen Aaby","M",24,NA,NA,"Denmark","DEN","1920 Summer",1920,"Summer","Antwerpen","Football","Football Men's Football",NA
```

Comment: Show 2-3 rows of your CSV.

Comment: Importing using mysqlworkbench wizard? On windows?

Comment: yes using wizard and using mac

Comment: added 3 rows of dataset

Comment: Looks like you forget to set "skip 1 line", and workbench tries to import the first, header, line..